# App Script Shopify GraphQL Request - 400 response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, graphql, shopify-api

I am trying to call Shopify's GraphQL API via Google App Script.

I have successfully made the call via Postman using the same body and authentication values and that has been working fine.

However, when calling the API via App Script I keep receiving a 400 response code, with the following error message `{"errors":{"query":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}`

Here is the code I am using:

```
function shopifySync() {
    var url = "https://store-name.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/graphql.json";
    var payloaddata = `query {orders(first: 20) { edges { node { id } } } }`;

    var payload = JSON.stringify(payloaddata);
    var password = "api_password"; //Private Shopify App


    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        'method': "POST",
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': { "X-Shopify-Access-Token": password , "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        'payload': payload
    },
    );

    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
}
```

In Shopify's documentation the 400 HTTP response is classified as "Bad Request" and the explanation is:

> The request was not understood by the server, generally due to bad syntax or because the Content-Type header was not correctly set to application/json.
> This status is also returned when the request provides an invalid code parameter during the OAuth token exchange process.

Source: https://shopify.dev/api/usage/response-codes

How can I resolve this issue and successfully call Shopify's GraphQL API?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the GraphQL documentation of another Saas company.

The issue was how the payload was formatted

How I tried it:

```
'payload': payload
```

How it should be:

```
'payload': JSON.stringify({'query': payloaddata})
```

Final code that is working for me with the 2021-07 GraphQL API for Shopify:

```
    var url = "https://store-name.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/graphql.json";
    var payloaddata = 'query {orders(first: 20) { edges { node { id } } } }';

    var password = "api_password";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        'method': "POST",
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': { "X-Shopify-Access-Token": password , "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        'payload': JSON.stringify({'query': payloaddata})
    });
```